# The linux/driver/video Makefile , contains no rules?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, raspbian

I need some kernel module files:

```
sysfillrect.ko
syscopyarea.ko
sysimgblt.ko
fb_sys_fops.ko
```

They are supposed to exist in `linux/drivers/video`
but they are not present. Instead I found these files with the same name but with a `.c` suffix and a `makefile`. However, when I use`make` or `make modules`, it says that there's no rule for this. How can I use this `makefile`?

(I use raspian wheezy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build video driver alone.

cd linux

make drivers/video/

Comment: This didn't generate .ko files , instead it generated object files

Comment: Check your config. If you configured it as y it will not generate .ko update your config to M and compile